# How to write unit tests for Spark Streaming programs?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, apache-spark, spark-streaming, scalatest

I'm relatively new to using Spark Streaming. I've been searching for the best way to write unit tests for my Spark application and came across the `TestSuiteBase` trait.

However, I'm unable to extend this trait in my test suite.

Here's the code snippet releant to this issue:

```
... 
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD 
import org.apache.spark.streaming._ 
import org.apache.spark.streaming.TestSuiteBase
... 
... 
class UnitTest extends BaseTest with TestSuiteBase
...
```

However, I hit this error when running sbt test:

```
.... object TestSuiteBase is not a member of package org.apache.spark.streaming
[error] import org.apache.spark.streaming.TestSuiteBase
```

**Also, are there any better approaches to writing unit tests for Spark Streaming programs?**

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: were you able to download the jar using sbt ? I am also facing the same issue .

Answer (score 0):

I modified my "build.sbt" to contain:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.4.0" classifier "tests"
```

This will include the test jars for spark streaming, which contains TestSuiteBase